# How to pass image from one View to Previous view from Gallery in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I was successfully fetched an image from gallery and It was appearing in second screen.But when I click on done button this image is send to previous screen.

**Below is detailed explanation**

1)First screen initially one image.
2)When I click on this image it navigate into second screen and it ask choose from gallery
3)I was choose from gallery one image and this image is appearing in second screen.
4)When I was click on done button in second screen it will navigate into previous screen that is first screen and the image will be change with selected image

How to pass my image into previous screen and set with the selected image.

**MprofileViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AddProfileViewController.h"
@class MProfileViewController;

@interface MProfileViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,ImageSelectionDelegate>
{    
    NSMutableArray* titles;
    IBOutlet UITableView *mainTableView;
    IBOutlet  UIImageView *image2;
}
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIImageView *image2;


@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *titles;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UITableView *mainTableView;

-(IBAction) clickEventOnImage:(id) sender;

@end
```

**MprofileViewController.m**

```
#import "MProfileViewController.h"

@interface MProfileViewController ()
@end

@implementation MProfileViewController

@synthesize titles,mainTableView;
@synthesize image2;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    titles=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"View Profile";
 image2.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"hariku-indah.jpg"];
}

- (void) imageSelected:(UIImage *)image {
    // Use image
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction) clickEventOnImage:(id) sender{
    AddProfileViewController *Avc = [[AddProfileViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddProfileViewController" bundle:nil];
    Avc.delegate=self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:Avc animated:YES];
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

}
@end
```

**AddProfileViewController.h**

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ImageSelectionDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) imageSelected:(UIImage*)image;
@end

@interface AddProfileViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
    NSData *dataImage;
}

// Delegate property
@property (nonatomic,assign) id<ImageSelectionDelegate> delegate;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end
```

**AddProfileViewController.m**

```
#import "MProfileViewController.h"

@interface AddProfileViewController ()
@property(strong,nonatomic) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;

@end

@implementation AddProfileViewController
@synthesize imageView;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"actionSheet");
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [self pushTakePhotoScreenInDelegate];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        [self pushChoosePhotoScreenInDelegate];
    }

}
-(void)pushTakePhotoScreenInDelegate
{
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"viewfinder_2.png"]];
    CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -52/2.0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)];
    self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = imageView;
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)pushChoosePhotoScreenInDelegate
{
    self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}


//-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    self.imageView.image = image;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

// In case you are using image picker, this delegate is called once image selection is complete.

//- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
//didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
//{
    //Use either according to your setting, whether you allow image editing or not.
    //self.imageView.image = image;
//UIImage *myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    //For edited image
   // UIImage *myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    //if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imageSelected:)]) {
     //   [self.delegate imageSelected:myImage];
   // }
//}


 /*
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage * pickedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    AddProfileViewController * controller = [AddProfileViewController new];
    controller.imageView.image = pickedImage;
   // [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}*/
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select Image from..."
        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo", @"Choose from library", nil];
        actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
        actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
        [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    }

-(IBAction)back:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
//   if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imageSelected:)]) {
//        [self.delegate imageSelected:imageView];
//    }

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}
@end
```

Comment: Use block ......Or custom delegate..

Comment: How to do please provide me some code

Comment: On review of your code i think ypu have already implemnted custom delegate ,,,i want to know what error exactly ,are you getting??

Comment: @user2694118 your selected image convert in data and pass data in your previous view.

Answer (score -1):

In your AddprileViewController.h file create UIimage object as

```
 UIImage *_gImage;
```

and set property as

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *_gImage;
```

in .m file synthesize this object

```
  @synthesize _gImage;
```

set image in _gImage object

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
self.imageView.image = image;

//add image in globle object
_gImage = image;

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

in your MprofileViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 if(!Avc) {
 Avc = [[AddProfileViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddProfileViewController" bundle:nil];
 }
if (Avc._gImage != nil) {
 image2.image=Avc._gImage;
}
else {
 image2.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"hariku-indah.jpg"];
}
```

}

Hope this will solve your problem.

set this as global object.

```
  Avc = [[AddProfileViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddProfileViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: What is set as global object where can I set.And the image was not changing.

Comment: AddProfileViewController *Avc   set this object as global object.

Comment: How set this as global object

Comment: AddProfileViewController *Avc set in .h file and when you are alloc this obj then if(!Avc){ Avc = [[AddProfileViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddProfileViewController" bundle:nil]; } in viewWillAppear.

Comment: I can't understand please can you explain me brifely

Comment: Not changing the image in first screen,need any modifications

Answer (score -1):

make a variable in your app delegate and synthesize it like this

In AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UIImage *myImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *myImage;
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize myImage;
```

then create AppDelegate instance in your view controller in your AddprileViewController.m

```
-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage * pickedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    AddProfileViewController * controller = [AddProfileViewController new];
    controller.imageView.image = pickedImage;

   AppDelegate *appDel=(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication SharedApplication].delegate;
     appDelegate.myImage=pickedImage;
}
```

now the selected image stored in myImage Variable and now you can use it anywhere you want

Comment: these two errors are occurring No known class method for selector shared application and property delegate not found in object of type id